# What's the minimal iOS version that Google ML Kit support?

Tags: ios, google-mlkit

When I integrate ML Kit to my app, I wonder which is the minimum supported version of iOS? The document only mentioned the minimum supported version of Xcode.

Comment: "*The document*" *What* document, exactly? Can you link it?

Comment: @esqew This one: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration/ios

Answer (score 1):

Currently the minimum supported iOS version is iOS 10. We will try to make this explicit on the page, thanks for asking.